# TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress with Jersey + Guice + JPA

Tags: jpa, jersey, guice, guice-3, guice-persist

Using Guice 3.0, following this tutorial: https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/JPA

GuiceModule class:

```
public class GuiceModule extends ServletModule {

@Override
protected void configureServlets() {
  // start the service
  bind(JPAInitializer.class).asEagerSingleton();

  // PersistFilter
  filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);

  // jpa + guice
  install(new JpaPersistModule("drone-cloud"));

  // bindings
  bind(UserService.class).to(UserServiceImpl.class);
  bind(TwoFactorAuthenticator.class).to(GoogleAuthenticator.class);
  bind(ImageQueue.class).asEagerSingleton();
  bind(DroneCloudServerHandler.class).asEagerSingleton();
 }
}
```

JPAInitializer.class

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.persist.PersistService;

public class JPAInitializer {
   @Inject
   JPAInitializer(PersistService service) {
      service.start();
   }
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/mission")
public class MissionController {

   @Inject
   Provider<EntityManager> _em;

   @Path("/new")
   @POST
   @Transactional
   public String newMission(SimpleMission mission) {

      _em.get().persist(mission);
      _em.get().flush();
      _em.get().close();

      return "{ \"mission_id\": \"" + mission.getId() + "\" }";
   }
}
```

And the stacktrace:

javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
    at com.drone.mission.controller.MissionController.newMission(MissionController.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:106)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:259)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: No idea what's wrong but I had similar problem and finally did similar mechanism for handling transactions :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There problem was that the `MissionController` class is managed by Jersey, and *not* by Guice, so it wasn't intercepted by the `JpaLocalTxnInterceptor`

I solved it by moving DB-related code to another class, like this:

```
class MissionController {
    @Inject MissionDao dao;
    ....
}


public class MissionDao {
   @Inject Provider<EntityManager> em;

   @Transactional
   public void save(SimpleMission mission) {
      em.get().persist(mission);
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Could You please prepare a sample app on GH?

Comment: I've cloned the project but I can't reproduce the problem. Does this sample project expose the problem well?

Comment: no, this project doesn't have the problem, as the DB related code is done on a class that's injected into the Jersey controller

Comment: The problem was what I described in the solution